# How can I set the default font in LibreOffice or Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, libreoffice-writer

When I open Microsoft Word, Excel or LibreOffice Writer, I need to have a default font configured.

How can I set this up in LibreOffice / Microsoft Office under Linux (e.g. Ubuntu), Windows XP or Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### LibreOffice Writer

The easiest way is to set up [a default template](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template), which will have this font selected.

> The default template contains the default formatting information for
>   new text documents. If you want, you can create a new template and use
>   it as the default template.
>
> #### To Create a Default Template
>
> - Create a document and the content and formatting styles that you want.
> - Choose **File - Templates - Save**.
> - In the **New Template** box, type a name for the new template.
> - In the **Categories** list, select "My Templates", and then click OK.
> - Choose **File - Templates - Organize**.
> - In the **Templates** list, double-click the "My Templates" folder.
> - Right-click the template that you created, and choose **Set as Default Template**. Click **Close**.

### Microsoft Word

A similar procedure for [changing the default template ("Normal.dot") in Word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-the-normal-template-normal-dot-HP001121028.aspx).

> - On the **File** menu, click **Open**, and then navigate to C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates.
> - If no templates are listed in the **Open** dialog box, click the arrow next to the Files of type box, and then click **Document Templates**.
> - Double-click the **Normal.dot** file to open it. To be certain that you're working in the default template, check to see that Normal.dot
>     appears in the Word title bar.
> - Make any changes you want, using the menus and dialog boxes just as you would to change default settings for a document, but remember that
>     any changes you make to Normal.dot will be applied to documents that
>     you create in the future.
> - When you have finished, on the Standard toolbar, click **Save**.

Comment: this is perfect.